# Sunspot Solr in production

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, lucene, solr, sunspot

I have need to deploy my app to production now that uses sunspot for search.

I see some sources saying not to run the sunspot solr instance in production but to setup on tomcat, but others have said you can run sunspot in production ?

Please can anyone tell me which is best to use in production and why?  Obviously just running sunspot in production will be alot quicker to setup but i dont want problems caused by this.

Also i have seen that you should turn off auto commits, is this best practice ?   and if so how do you do commits?   a cron or delayed job or something ?

If anyone has a tutorial / article or example setup i can see for reference ?

thanks a lot
Rick

Comment: anybody help with this ? please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using http://websolr.com ?